# Do I get a 422 HTTP code even though I am logged in?

Tags: laravel

Do I get a 422 HTTP code even though I am logged in?
From my blade I send an XHR post request. In the route I use the auth middleware. This works. This means you have to be logged in to send the post.

**web.php**

```php
Route::post('/posts', [PostController::class, 'store'])->middleware(['web', 'auth'])->name('posts.store');
```

Now I created my own request class to validate the sent data.

**PostStoreRequest authorise method**

```php
public function authorize()
{
    return false;
}
```

Since I use my own custom request class I get this error message even though I am logged in:

```
This action is unauthorized.", exception: "Symfony\\Component\\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\AccessDeniedHttpException
```

**I wonder why this is?**

Comment: *"I wonder why this is?"* - You're returning `false` from `authorize()`, so it's triggering an unauthorized error. Am I missing something here?

Comment: As Tim said, you must either return `true` (literally and that is done by default, see [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/52e2229588ca65dddc9bd89053ab7194b7800c3d/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/FormRequest.php#L176-L185)) or you must write an expression so it returns `true` or `false`. And the error code is `401` , not `422` (validation not passed)

Comment: @TimLewis A form sends data for two models. Do I need two request classes for validation?

I have just realised that I have misunderstood the method. As MikeLowrey https://stackoverflow.com/a/74826767/18066399  writes in his answer, this is about whether the user is authorised. Thanks for your comment and sorry for my blindness. Have a nice weekend!

Comment: No worries! I just wasn't sure if I was missing something else, since returning hard-coded `false` _should_ have that effect, based on it's purpose and definition. All good! And yes; you can have as many request classes as you'd like  They're simply a nice way to separate Controller logic from Validation logic, as typically, you'd do something like `$request->validate(...)`, or `$validator = Validator::make(...)` in the Controller, which can then bloat it significantly. I typically use a FormRequest for Create and Update for each Model, and `$request->validate()` for one-off misc Requests 

Comment: @Thank you very much! Can you read thoughts :-) How do you know that I have also asked myself this question whether one may use several request classes?

Comment: Well, you did ask *"Do I need two request classes for validation?"* , which I realize is now a slightly different question than I answered. I don't believe it's possible to use 2 different request classes at once, since the way you hook them up is via injection, like `public function whatever(RequestClass $exampleRequestClass)`, and you can't inject 2 of them. But the FormRequest should validate the data being sent, so as long as you validate with that context in mind, it's perfectly fine to include validation for `model_one_field => X` and `model_two_field => Y`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to check in the `authorize()` method if the user is authorised for this action. If you have a role system right you can implement this here. For example, only users with the Writer role are allowed to create a post. If you don't have that and you just allow everyone who is logged in, then change the return to true or return `auth()->check()`.

Example without role system:

```php
public function authorize()
{
    return true;
    // or
    return auth()->check();
}
```

With role System:

```
public function authorize()
{
    return auth()->user()?->isWriter();
}
```

**Important Note:** Thank to @matiaslauriti &&  @Tpojka for the right advice / good review.

Comment: You can directly do `return auth()->user()->isWriter()`, and if it does not return a boolean, just do `return (bool) auth()->user()->isWriter()`

Comment: @matiaslauriti You are absolutely right! I have corrected it. Thanks to you! ;-)

Comment: Could be needed null-safe `(bool) auth()->user()?->isWriter()` just for case user doesn't exist there.

Comment: @Tpojka. Thanks to you! I have just improved it! Thanks for the good review! It is really a great pleasure to work with you and matiaslauriti!

Comment: You are most welcome. And @matiaslauriti 's advice to cast what is returned to boolean is also great, because if `null` is returned it wouldn't correctly check strict condition like `[pseudo_code]if (false === $request->authorize()) {}[/pseudo_code]`.

Comment: Agreed on all the points, great answer and comments, just be aware that `?->` (safe navigation/null-safe, whatever you want to call it) was [added in PHP 8](https://www.php.net/releases/8.0/en.php#nullsafe-operator); if you're still using PHP 7.4 (or less, but hopefully not as all of those are now [end of life](https://www.php.net/supported-versions.php)), you'll need to do something like `return auth()->user() ? (bool)auth()->user()->isWriter() : false;` 